# Python DataFrame grouped conditional mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` DataFrame with two columns `date` and `value` (3k different dates, 800k total rows)

I would like to calculate the mean value grouped by date, but only for the values in the bottom decile.

I have tried using `DCL = df['date','value'].groupby(['date'])['value'].quantile(.1)`, which gives me the `cutoff` value for the bottom decile, for each date, how can I then create a conditional mean for each date, so that it only uses the values lower than `DCL` (for each date)?

```
DCL = df['date','value'].groupby(['date'])['value'].quantile(.1)
...
2017-01-26   0.067924
2017-01-27   0.067719
2017-01-30   0.068561
2017-01-31   0.068056
2017-02-01   0.067988
2017-02-02   0.068306
2017-02-03   0.068311
2017-02-06   0.067923
2017-02-07   0.067192
2017-02-08   0.066902
2017-02-09   0.065978
2017-02-10   0.065414
2017-02-13   0.065402
2017-02-14   0.065939
2017-02-15   0.065519
```

The cutoff is different for each day, I would then like to calculate the mean of 'value' grouped by each day only using the numbers for that date that are lower than the cutoff for that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `transform` to add a new column for the decile mean for current row date.

```
df['DCL'] = df[['date','value']].groupby(['date'])['value'].\
               transform(lambda g: g[g <= g.quantile(.1)].mean())
```